# Is a question asking to explain the details of a software patent lawsuit on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

This article https://www.nytimes.com/2020/10/07/us/supreme-court-google-oracle.html?action=click&module=Latest&pgtype=Homepage (and I'm sure there are others) discusses a patent lawsuit between Google & Oracle over ... something to do with Google's right to use Java or parts of Java's implementation in Android.

The article doesn't explain in sufficient depth what the real issue is, understandably maybe for a general audience.

Would a SO question asking for someone to explain what the relevant software details of the lawsuit be on-topic? (Not about the legal aspects themselves.)

---

If not, any suggestions where this might be on-topic?

Comment: @JeanneDark thanks, but I wasn't thinking to ask about the legal aspects, but to explain the actual source code which Google is using.

Comment: No it would not be on-topic. Its not a programming problem. Additionally it would be too broad.

Comment: Did you read the article about [Google’s 9 lines](https://majadhondt.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/googles-9-lines/)? I can't imagine the lawsuit is very different really. I can't imagine any site on the network that would be able to go into the specifics of this lawsuit though.

Comment: @Scratte aha thanks, I hadn't heard it referred to as "9 lines".

Comment: FWIW I could understand a potential copyright violation, but patenting that seems ridiculous.

Comment: It is quite funny and tragic at the same time. Note that the 9th line consists of nothing more than `}`.. wonder if I just broke some copyright rule there though ;)

Comment: In that case just use a tab instead of a space before the }

Comment: If anything... we actually have [patents.se] and also [law.se]...

Comment: Those that recommend [law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) should probably read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about "Please don't ask questions seeking legal advice on a specific matter". While this may not be seeking legal advice, it's a specific matter. And I'm not sure they'd be able to identify the 11.000 lines of code in the lawsuit.

Comment: @Scratte I don't think the would ask it like that. They would probably ask it like "Imagine a hypothetical situation where, [so and so]. What are the legal implications of this?". Asking stuff hypothetically would be perfectly acceptable on Law. In fact that's what you have to do there.

Comment: @10Rep The author wants to know the specifics of this particular lawsuit. They want to know "relevant software details of the lawsuit". Not hypothetical software details..

Comment: @Scratte To defend myself, I would leave mine after yours, since it's possible to look at it both ways.

Comment: @10Rep At least you don't need to hire a lawyer ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

It has nothing to do with programming.  It has *everything* to do with licenses and other legal implications, which isn't what we touch.

Comment: It *might* belong on https://law.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Or *[Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/tour)*.